# Proving that $\sin n\theta\leq n\sin\theta$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove this complex inequality.
$$ \mid \Im{(z^n)}\mid\leq n\mid z^{n-1}\mid \mid\Im{(z)}\mid $$

Where $n$ is a positive integer.

This inequality is equivalent to proving:
$$\sin (n\theta)\leq n\sin\theta$$
How do you prove this?

Comment: Do we have a range for $\theta$? If not, there are loads of counterexamples.

Comment: The range is simply the range for the argument of a complex number, $$(-\pi,\pi]$$.

Comment: The inequality is false for any $\theta$ for which there is a $k\in\Bbb Z$ satisfying $(2k-1)\pi<\theta<2k\pi$, regardless of the value of $n$. Graphed [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j2e9aal23i). $(-\pi, 0)$ is in this range

Answer (score 1):

If the inequality is required in $[0,\pi /2]$ a simple induction argument using $\sin (n+1)\theta =\sin (n\theta) \cos \theta +\cos n \theta \sin (\theta)$ can be used.